# Fetch data from a text file using php

Tags: php, html, search, text-files

i have a text file that i created with another php script that has inside information like: Names, phones and addresses. in a format like that:
Name
phone
address
and i want with another php script to search that text file given a name. if the name exists then it will put the results under the search box, if not then it will display an error message.
here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Phonebook Search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">//my search box.
            <div><h1>Phonebook Search</h1>
                <label>Enter name: <input type="text" name="name" /></label>
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </div>
        </form>

        <?php
            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")//the condition after pressing the search button.
            {
                $name = $_POST["name"];
                $filename = 'phonebook.txt';
                $file = file_get_contents($filename);
                if (strpos($file, "$name"))
                {
                    echo "$name";
                }

                $lines = file("phonebook.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

any help would be appriciated. if you need more information i will provide.

Comment: Where are you stuck actually?

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. when i write a name in the search box(a name i know it exists, to test it) it doesn't find the name to show it to me.

Comment: Why are you passing `"$name"` to the `strpos` instead of the variable `$name`? Furthermore, you have to check for `strpos(...) !== false`, because a position of `0` will be evaluated as `FALSE` as well (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). Using `!==` for comparison makes sure that it's actually a boolean and not a `0`.

Comment: Storing the data in a different format like JSON makes this much easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to cleaning up some small parts of your code (replacing `"$name"` with `$name`), you have to check for `strpos(...) !== false`, because a position of `0` will be evaluated as `FALSE`. Have a look at [php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)). `!==` will consider the type and not only the value of both variables.

```php
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Phonebook Search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">//my search box.
            <div><h1>Phonebook Search</h1>
                <label>Enter name: <input type="text" name="name" /></label>
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </div>
        </form>

        <?php
            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
            {
                $name = $_POST["name"];
                $filename = 'phonebook.txt';
                $file = file_get_contents($filename);

                // transform $name to e.g. lowercase (ignores case entered by user)

                if (strpos($file, $name) !== false)
                {
                    echo $name;
                }

                // what is this needed for?
                $lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I agree to @PeterSH's comment: use another format like `JSON` that has a predefined structure you can search in or use a database.

Comment: thank you that worked. But is it going to show the rest of the persons information, like the phone and address?

Comment: No, you have programmed that it `echo` the `$name`. For implementing this behavior, we need to know how your text file is structured, i.e. if every new line is one person's record or a different format is used. In general, several tutorials exist for this, e.g. https://www.tutorialsmade.com/find-string-get-line-number-file-using-php/

Comment: Thank you i think i found how to do it. The text files structure is like this:   Name (one line ) Phone (second line) Address (third line) and i wanted to show all three lines when the search was founding the name as many times it found it in the file. now i am trying to show an error message if the name doesn't exist

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem to help other users to find a solution faster!